# how can i save values with arithmetic operators in mysql with php?

Tags: php, mysql, operators, arithmetic-expressions

I have a field datatype VARCHAR in mysql. 
It has to save data like `495/1,495/2` but when i am running query from PHP it save in mysql like `495, 247.5`. so basically mysql divides the values.

Then I have tried this

```
$sfno = $_POST['sfno']; // i am getting value from HTML form the value is 495/2    
$sfno = explode("/",$sfno);
$sfnom = "$sfno[0]"."-"."$sfno[1]";
```

then mysql subtract the values and save them as `494,493`

so how can i save arithmetic operators in mysql database?

[image]

Comment: `$sfno = "497/2";` and then save it.

Comment: How is the value in the $_POST created?

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable from the HTML form where user input the value like `495/1,495/2` etc

Comment: @Jaiffable What happens when you do what Criesto said?
Does it work?

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable NO PHP is working fine but when it goes to mysql it divides the value and save them

Comment: Maybe this (note the single quotes around the variables but inside the double quotes): `$sfnom = "'$sfno[0]'"."-"."'$sfno[1]'";` If the values appear between quotes in the sql query it won't dare to calculate it

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable it gets error `Unknown column '2f2' in 'field list'`

Comment: @Jaiffable then i guess that it does not know the colum '2f2'. Can you post your query code?

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable `$query = "INSERT INTO sfarea(sfareaid,sfno,sftotarea,sfremarea)values($nxtid,$sfnom,$sfarea,$sfremarea)";`

Comment: `%2f` is url encoded for `/`, try URL decoding it (`$decoded = urldecode('%2f')`) before putting it in the query.

Comment: @ThisNameBetterBeAvailable No it's also not working plz check this  [link](http://postimg.org/image/xcc2oiq77/)

Comment: @Jaiffable See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the variable between quotes in the query string to prevent calculation.

```
$sfnom = "$sfno[0]"."-"."$sfno[1]";
```

Becomes (note the single quotes inside the string):

```
$sfnom = "'$sfno[0]"."-"."$sfno[1]'";
```

You also need to URL decode it (%2f is `/`, otherwise it will contain `2f` instead of `/`):

```
$sfnom = urldecode("'$sfno[0]"."-"."$sfno[1]'");
```

So `INSERT INTO sfarea(sfareaid,sfno,sftotarea,sfsoldarea) values(2003,495/2,9854,0)` becomes:

```
 INSERT INTO sfarea(sfareaid,sfno,sftotarea,sfsoldarea) values(2003,'495/2',9854,0)
```

Only way you are going to store arithmetic operators is as a string, so you need quotes around it.